# ng-click not working in ionic application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is my simple code for a demo Ionic Application.

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="catego">

  <ion-pane >
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-positive">        
    <button class="button icon ion-navicon"></button>
    <h1 class="title">Hardware Shop</h1>    
    <button class="button button-clear  icon ion-plus-circled" ng-click="popover.show($event)"></button>         
  </ion-header-bar>

  <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-search"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search item" ng-model="searchitem"/>
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="clear()">NOTWORKING</button>
    </label>
  </div>

  <ion-content class="has-subheader" style="padding:5px !important;">
    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Refreshing..." on-refresh="dorefresh()"></ion-refresher>
      <div class="list" >
        <div ng-repeat="element in data | filter : searchitem| orderBy : 'category'">
          <div class="item item-divider">{{ element.category }}</div>
          <ion-list can-swipe="true">
            <ion-item class=""  href="#" ng-repeat="innerelement in element.companies | filter : searchitem | orderBy : 'toString()' track by $index">
          ---   {{innerelement}}&nbsp;<br/>
            <ion-option-button class="button-positive icon ion-edit"></ion-option-button>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </div>
      </div>
   </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
```

The button in my subheader which says NOTWORKING is not working. I have made sure that there are no errors in the console and all other methods are working fine. Is there something I am missing?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `clear()` function part of the catego controller?

Comment: Yes of course. It is a method on $scope.

Comment: If your clear() method tries to clear your searchitem, the two-way binding might not work. Always make ng-model variables part of an object in order to make two-way binding work properly ( for instance: ng-model="config. searchitem", and in controller scope.config.searchitem="")

Comment: I removed all that code while debugging from the clear(). Now it just has a JS alert("hello"); even which does not work. So, I guess something is preventing the method from being called.

Comment: Might be helpful to include the js code.

Comment: A Fiddle of the code would be great, or at least the js controller code :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to move the `<button>` outside the `<label>` as in the code below:

```
   <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-search"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search item" ng-model="searchitem" />
      </label>
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="clear()">NOTWORKING</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: That actually worked. An explanation would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Simply check Ionic docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#bar-inputs. I think `item-input-wrapper` CSS class is intended only to style label with an input field. Other elements must be outside the label tag.

Comment: Do you mean that JavaScript is conflicting?

Comment: I don't know exactly what happens, we should review Ionic code... however according to docs and examples the CSS class is used only this way

Answer (score 0):

I found better this, This is working fine on my app, Nice gesture on Ios Also

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {  

       $('*[ng-click]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("ng-click");
            $(this).attr("on-touch", $(this).attr("ng-click"));
        });
});
```